# Why doing quicksort on sorted array would give n1 = 0 and n2 = n - 1?

Tags: algorithm, sorting, quicksort

Professor told me that quicksort on sorted array would keep on giving n2 = n - 1, n - 2 so on. I don't quite understand how it would equal to n - 1 and the whole concept really confuses me. Anyone could help?

This is what I mean:
[image]

Comment: There are a multitude of quick sort variants, and this claim cannot be made for all of them. Furthermore, we have to guess what is meant with n and n2. You should clarify your question and pinpoint which is the quick sort variant you are referring to, and what you mean with n2.

Comment: NB: the image does not explain what n2 is, or which quick sort variant you are referring to.

Answer (score 0):

There are variants of quick sort. As [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort#Choice_of_pivot) states:

> #### Choice of pivot
>
> In the very early versions of quicksort, the leftmost element of the partition would often be chosen as the pivot element. Unfortunately, this causes worst-case behavior on already sorted arrays, which is a rather common use-case. The problem was easily solved by choosing either a random index for the pivot, choosing the middle index of the partition or (especially for longer partitions) choosing the median of the first, middle and last element of the partition for the pivot (as recommended by Sedgewick).

It seems you are referring to a version that has this worst case behaviour when given a sorted array. [Lumoto's partitioning scheme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort#Lomuto_partition_scheme) is such a version:

> #### Lomuto partition scheme
>
> This scheme is attributed to Nico Lomuto and popularized by Bentley in his book Programming Pearls and Cormen et al. in their book Introduction to Algorithms. This scheme chooses a pivot that is typically the last element in the array. The algorithm maintains index `i` as it scans the array using another index `j` such that the elements at `lo` through `i-1` (inclusive) are less than the pivot, and the elements at `i` through `j` (inclusive) are equal to or greater than the pivot. As this scheme is more compact and easy to understand, it is frequently used in introductory material, although it is less efficient than Hoare's original scheme e.g., when all elements are equal. This scheme degrades to O(²) when the array is already in order.

An example should clarify the point:

Let's say the input array is [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]: the right-most value serves as pivot. The partitioning algorithm will not have to swap anything (because values are already sorted), and without change returns the index of the pivot. The recursive quick sort calls are then made on the subarray *before* that index, and the subarray *after* that index. But that second subarray is empty. And the first subarray just has one element less:

[1,2,3,4,5,6]

And then the story repeats itself with the pivot value 6.